# Percent Signs in Django URLConf regex

Tags: django, django-urls

Have to take some old, strange URLs and redirect them permanently to new, flashy URLs.

One such strange URL is one with spaces in the file name, example: `file%20name%20here.htm`

When I add this to my URLConf it does not redirect to the new page. It simply 404s on the unredirect URL.

Here's what I've got:

`(r'^file%20name%20here\.htm', redirect_to, {'url': '/flashy-url/'}),`

As I said this does not redirect, it 404s. I figured that perhaps it was treating the `%`'s funny, so I tried escaping them: `\%` to no avail.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%20` is the same as a space in URLs. Try:

```
(r'^file name here\.htm', redirect_to, {'url': '/flashy-url/'}),
```